# Head pose estimation with Opencv

Tags: opencv, 3d, face-detection

I am using OpenCV Haar Algorithm to track the Head and overlay an image over the Head.
What I am doing is saving frames generated by camera and overlaying image over each frames.
And time is not a constraint as I am not doing it Real-Time.

My code is working fine for say 45 degree of left and right rotation of Head.
But I need something which will track up to 90 degree of rotation.

Even I got many reference of OpenCV functions and [link to estimate Head Pose](http://www.morethantechnical.com/2010/03/19/quick-and-easy-head-pose-estimation-with-opencv-w-code/)

Please provide me some reference. Code Examples will be cool.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi I would like to know if you are successful in finding the head-pose. My intention is to do it in real time video capture. Is that possible with POSIT? Can you help me with some example are codes?

Comment: Can you please guide me on how u have done this?

Comment: I have posted a question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21732367/head-pose-estimation-in-real-time-video

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a functionc in openCV called POSIT that permit to estimate the pose of 3d object in a single image. It implements POSIT algorithm. Try to have a look there.

Comment: I am talking about Head (Face) Pose Estimation & Not 3d Object...Help me out with some code...

Comment: You can consider the head as a 3d object and estimate its position through that algorithm!

Answer (score 7):

You can use an algorithm like SURF (you have samples in OpenCV package) and use it over a picture of the face, the over the image, and then use SURF descriptors to match the points and estimate the 3d position of the face in the image.
You can use the same code on the sample "find_obj" but replace the image by the face picture you want to track.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Idea is cool..I appreciate it...But what about it being implemented in real time video for different faces....

Comment: Well, for real time you could use FAST algorithm instead of SURF (also in openCV libraries), but of course you'll have to deal with occlusions.

Comment: Link "Here" is broken. Kindly check.

Answer (score 5):

You could check the EHCI project at http://code.google.com/p/ehci/ as it gives a nice overview about POSIT and Lukas Kanade.

Comment: Sorry I was busy during that time....Have u checked out this web site http://www.iamironman2.com/uk/

Comment: Wow, that's nice. DFusion algorithm is working very well. Although I believe it is sort of expensive. Kind regards,