# Head Pose estimation in real-time video

Tags: opencv, image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision

I need to do head pose estimation in live camera video. I have tried with few options like POSIT and [shervin Emami's code](https://github.com/MasteringOpenCV/code/tree/master/Chapter7_HeadPoseEstimation).

The problem is that I couldnt find any code that uses live video as input. Can anyone suggest good opensource code or methods to find head-pose.

**Input:** Frames from the camera.

**Expected output:** Finding the pose of the face.

It would be great if I get an links or codes if any. Also I am planning to do the same application in Android and IOS so like to have few useful links which may help me.

Comment: Where you able to run Shervin Emami's code on an image?

Comment: @AnoopK.Prabhu I have seen it and he is using some training and all. And it is only for images, So I havent tried compiling or running it.

Comment: Make it working on an image and modify it to work on a video or camera input

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [OpenPose](https://github.com/CMU-Perceptual-Computing-Lab/openpose), it's a real-time multi-person system to jointly detect human body, hand, and facial keypoints (in total 130 keypoints) on single images. Using a CNN, it's a great  example of Deep Learning in the field of computer vision.

OpenPose is originally build with Caffe, but ports to TensorFlow are starting to emerge. For example this [github repo](https://github.com/ildoonet/tf-pose-estimation), is a implementation of OpenPose using TensorFlow. In addition, the new model is bases on Mobilenet, which makes it more fit to run on CPU or low-power embedded devices (like a smartphone for example). BTW, TensorFlow supports both Android and iOS!